# Blood Test Panel for weight loss in females

Tags: blood-tests, weight, metabolism, hormonal-imbalance

Is there a well regarded medical/academic type of blood panel test or list of items to get tested for, when unable to loose weight, despite proper diet and exercise efforts?

For example, [this comes up](https://truweight.in/blog/weight-loss/list-of-blood-tests-for-weight-loss.html) in a quick Google search, however, was looking for something ***not*** tied to any marketing...but with more medical/academic credibility.

(Female, early 30's).

Comment: Thyroid testing (a complete set of those tests).

Comment: @l-b: please expand as answer...

Comment: Also found an actual panel from what seems to be a legit online lab and most of them items seem to match multiple sources: https://www.walkinlab.com/blog/blood-tests-can-help-manage-weight-loss/

Comment: @GregMcNulty That link expounds on my comment better than I could :)

Comment: It's too comprehensive, most wouldn't go that far on the first round of testing. They'd do some basic ones, then additional ones depending on what the history and physical suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The majority of people who are overweight have difficulty losing weight.  If they didn't there wouldn't be an obesity crisis in the western world.

> OBESITY CRISIS: TWO BILLION PEOPLE NOW OVERWEIGHT AND U.S. IS ONE OF THE FATTEST NATIONS ON EARTH [source](http://www.newsweek.com/obesity-crisis-us-childhood-overweight-two-billion-people-fattest-nations-624323)

Doing blood tests on 2 billion people who can't lose weight is almost a complete waste of money and resources.

As regards to a claim of a *proper diet* most people will tell you that they're on a good diet.  And almost always that is incorrect because their knowledge of nutrition is misinformed.  Again, if their knowledge were correct they would be less likely to be in this position. To support this at least one study has shown that nutritional knowledge is inversely correlated with healthy eating.

> Students with greater nutritional knowledge consumed less unhealthy fats and cholesterol. This finding magnifies the role of nutrition education as a potential tool in health campaigns to promote healthy eating patterns among college students. Results of this pilot study can inform the design of future nutrition education intervention studies to assess the efficacy of nutrition knowledge on pattern of fat consumption among college students. [1]

and

> Our results also demonstrate that black race and lower education within a low-income sample were independently related to misidentification of low nutrition and high caloric content foods. Misidentification was generally in the direction of believing that food items were healthier than they actually are. These findings are consistent with USDA survey results that found that black participants were less able than white participants to correctly identify foods with higher fat content [40]. [2]

If the physician considers that there might be an underlying issue, then [thyroid function](http://www.health.com/health/article/0,,20429749,00.html) might be the only reasonable test to perform if there are sufficient grounds on clinical suspicion.  Otherwise, consider the drugs and mental status of the person as eating is a common go-to activity for the depressed.

1. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5050673/
2. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3717981/
3. https://www.uptodate.com/contents/obesity-in-adults-behavioral-therapy

Comment: I strongly disagree with the statement "if their knowledge were correct they wouldn't be in this position."  Improving knowledge deficiencies does go a long way, yes. But there are so many other factors in play that this is not accurate, it is an oversimplification of a complex issue.

Comment: That's not my experience.  Almost all my overweight patients have a limited understanding of nutrition.

Comment: @DoctorWhom It's well known that poor eating habits and obesity are linked to socioeconomic status and education.  If you disagree, then provide a link to support your argument.

Comment: Sorry I somehow missed this response.  I disagree with how you had originally said it, but approve of your changes.  I of course agree that insufficient knowledge is often the PRIMARY barrier to appropriate weight management. However, Health Behavior is a field of study and a part of MPH training for a reason: health behavior changes rarely hinge on a single factor, and effectively encouraging change usually requires understanding and addressing multiple barrier factors.

Comment: I will see if I can recommend some resources, especially if you still have access to AccessMedicine or other textbook databases.  I also do lifestyle medicine consults in our primary care clinic, and it is a principle of LM training that a multi-factoral approach rooted in Health Behavior Change principles is much more successful in encouraging effective change than just providing knowledge - and that is what I see with my patients. Assessing sleep, mental health, and other factors impacting diet/exercise behaviors is part of our base visit template for a reason.

Comment: @DoctorWhom all my textbooks are out of date by over 30 years!  And at that time we didn't have a problem with obesity. But I do have uptodate

Comment: We do routinely do thyroid testing in most patients seriously struggling to lose weight, and I have seen weight gain be the only obvious presenting feature of hypothyroidism.  But that is rare. Usually it is not due to a clear secondary cause like that, it is a combination of nutrition knowledge + an assortment of other factors including commonly depression, anxiety, eating for comfort, daily routine, low self-awareness, and poor perception of self-efficacy.  Removing a nutritional knowledge barrier alone usually will not overcome the other factors if they are left unaddressed.

Comment: @DoctorWhom I think I mentioned most of those as well but doing 2 billion blood tests is a huge waste of time.  And the only reason I might do a thyroid test is because they always want to blame factors outside their control.

Comment: I agree that it has to be individualized, and I would disagree with pan-testing everyone who is overweight. I unfortunately think these labs where anyone can order their own serology are selling this blood test panel to a vulnerable audience.

Comment: UpToDate has a decent primer on it that includes a lot of the principles of health behavior analysis and change: https://www.uptodate.com/contents/obesity-in-adults-behavioral-therapy?topicRef=5371&source=see_link

Comment: @DoctorWhom I haven't read your link but cognitive therapy is often useful for a lot of problems.  Our problem is that we don't have psychologists with cognitive training. I have also studied motivational interviewing but it's very time consuming using this technique.  Leave it to the professionals!

Answer (score 2):

The list of tests in the link you posted is pretty complete. It is indeed a complete set of tests for that occasion.

[Here](http://www.webmd.com/diet/obesity/features/why-arent-you-losing-weight#1) is a bit more credible source though.

Keep in mind though, only a doctor can always recommend the appropriate tests if needed, not the internet.

Comment: Actually most doctors would not order the testosterone/estrogen/DHEA or stress hormones to start out with unless clinical history suggests something like PCOS. Usually they start with CMP CBC A1c Lipids TSH (and maybe T4/T3).  Additional testing depends on the history and physical exam, and then results of the first round of tests.